# Breaking out of nested loops in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, break, nested-loops

I have a nested loop, which is

```
while()
{
    for()
    {

    }
}
```

In my page I am trying to break the for loop and get into while loop without getting out of it. I tried `break;`, `break 1;` and `goto xxx;` and these did not work. Here is the code:

```
while( $results = pg_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{

    $url = $results['url'];
    for( $i = 0; $i < ($recordnum - 1); $i++ )
    {

        $urlpopup = $foldername . "/" . $namecomingform[$i];

        if( $url == $urlpopup )
        {

            $isthererecord = 'yes';

            goto getoutoffor;
        }
        else
        {

            $isthererecord = 'no';
        }
    }//end of for
    getoutoffor:

    if( $isthererecord == 'no' )
    {

        $sql = "UPDATE pictures SET erased='1' WHERE url='" . $url . "'";

        $run = pg_query( $sqlconnection, $sql );
    }
} //end of while
```

It seems like it checks for only one record from the database.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `break` should work without issues. are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: have you checked if the comparison `( $url == $urlpopup )` actually works as intended?

Comment: Your `for` loop relies on `$recordnum` which does not appear to be initialized anywhere.

Comment: You can use boolean variables instead of setting a string to 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: This is a part of my code, I am actually initializing it above of this part of the code.

Comment: http://php.net/break and probably http://php.net/goto - as you wrote you tested both, my comment is: "try harder" :) (both do work, prefer `break` in your case) - But actually, you don't need any looping here, just do some string analysis and test a number is within a certain range.

Comment: Even the comparison is not correct it should go through the while loop since I have more than one record in my database. I am printing the both records which are coming from the database and the array in the for loop. I get only one record printed in the while loop.

Comment: What happens if you run this: `while( $results = pg_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{ var_dump($results); }`? Do you get more than one record?

Comment: I am getting more than one record each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm a little late but I encountered a similar problem. Applied to your situation, what I would do is change the code to the following:

```
$LoopBreak = 'no';
while( $results = pg_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
if ($LoopBreak == 'yes') {
break;//Insert break statement here
}

else {    //This is First else

$url = $results['url'];
for( $i = 0; $i < ($recordnum - 1); $i++ )
{
    $urlpopup = $foldername . "/" . $namecomingform[$i];

    if( $url == $urlpopup )
    {
        $isthererecord = 'yes';
        $LoopBreak = 'yes'; //Variable added in place of break here
    }
    else
    {
        $isthererecord = 'no';
    }
}//end of for

if( $isthererecord == 'no' )
{
    $sql = "UPDATE pictures SET erased='1' WHERE url='" . $url . "'";
    $run = pg_query( $sqlconnection, $sql );
}

}//End First else
} //end of while
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably concerned about this part:

```
$url = $results['url'];
for( $i = 0; $i < ($recordnum - 1); $i++ )
{

    $urlpopup = $foldername . "/" . $namecomingform[$i];

    if( $url == $urlpopup )
    {

        $isthererecord = 'yes';

        goto getoutoffor;
    }
    else
    {

        $isthererecord = 'no';
    }
}//end of for
getoutoffor:
```

Read it. You loop here only to test that the number at the end of `$url` is between `0` and `$recordnum - 1`. Instead extract the prefix and the number from the string. Compare the prefix and if it matches, check if the number is within that range.

Doing that will also shed some light into a logical problem you have with the code more further on. From the wording of your question it looks like you're looking in the wrong place here so I hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: " You loop here only to test that the number at the end of $url is between 0 and $recordnum - 1." - how do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: `$isthererecord` is the result and the loop is done for the single `if` comparison in there only. The `$i` is representing a hashmap, which is the *range*.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, `break;` is what you should use. If your code does not work with break;, then it's most likely something else that is the problem, such as the if-statement check or the condition in the for-loop never being met (meaning that the for-loop never even starts). You should really debug your code more. **But don't use `goto`**. Use `break;`

Assuming that all the variables are correct, the code below should really work:

```
while( $results = pg_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
    $url = $results['url'];
    for( $i = 0; $i < ($recordnum - 1); $i++ )
    {
        $urlpopup = $foldername . "/" . $namecomingform[$i];

        if( $url == $urlpopup )
        {
            $isthererecord = 'yes';
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $isthererecord = 'no';
        }
    }//end of for

    if( $isthererecord == 'no' )
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE pictures SET erased='1' WHERE url='" . $url . "'";
        $run = pg_query( $sqlconnection, $sql );
    }
} //end of while
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way of dealing with this, but you can add an extra condition to your FOR loop, (**&& $isthererecord != 'yes'**) and initialize the **$isthererecord** variable before entering the loop, so your modified code would end up like below:

```
$isthererecord = '';
while ( $results = pg_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $url = $sorgusonucu['url'];
    for ( $i = 0; $i < ( $recordnum - 1 ) && $isthererecord != 'yes'; $i++ ) {
        $urlpopup = $foldername . "/" . $namecomingform[ $i ];

        if ( $url == $urlpopup ) {
            $isthererecord = 'yes';
            continue;
        }
        else {
            $isthererecord = 'no';
        }
    }

    if ( $isthererecord == 'no' ) {
        $sql = "UPDATE pictures SET erased = '1' WHERE url = '" . $url . "'";
        $run = pg_query( $sqlconnection, $sql );
    }
}
```

Comment: This still does not work. It only checks for only one record coming from database.

Comment: Then, as others have pointed out, you have a problem with your **if ( $url == $urlpopup )** condition... those variables are never equal, you should debug your code further

Comment: Even the comparison is not correct it should go through the while loop since I have more than one record in my database. I am printing the both records which are coming from the database and the array in the for loop. I get only one record printed in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

There was never a need for an else in the for loop

```
while ( $results = pg_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $url = $sorgusonucu['url'];
    for ( $i = 0; $i < ( $recordnum - 1 ) && $isthererecord != 'yes'; $i++ ) {
        $urlpopup = $foldername . "/" . $namecomingform[ $i ];

        if ( $url === $urlpopup ) {
            $sql = "UPDATE pictures SET erased = '1' WHERE url = '" . $url . "';";
            $run = pg_query( $sqlconnection, $sql );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```